# Adapt the derivatives to spherical coordinates

Tags: derivatives, spherical-coordinates

Let's consider the usual spherical coordinates:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = r \sin \theta \cos \phi\\
y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi\\
z = r \cos \theta
\end{cases}
$$
with $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\theta \in [0, \pi[$ and $\phi \in [0, 2\pi[$.

I need to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ using $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$. I did that a long time ago but totally forgot the method... What's the best way to find the answer ? Is there any shortcut since I don't need $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ ?

Comment: You’re asking for something that is covered in almost any article on spherical coordinates. Like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system?wprov=sfti1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the relation
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\left(\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}\right)^{T,-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}
\end{pmatrix}
$$